# Rotate subviews on rotating the parent view by the same angle

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I want to rotate a subview with the same angle, when its parent view is rotated. How do I  achieve this ?

```
- (void)rotationDetected:(UIRotationGestureRecognizer *)rotationRecognizer {   
    rotationRecognizer.rotation = M_PI_4;
    CGFloat angle = rotationRecognizer.rotation; 
    duplicateView.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(duplicateView.transform, angle); 
    userView.transform = duplicateView.transform; 
    rotationRecognizer.rotation = 0.0; 
}
```

Comment: Show us some code may be?

Comment: duplicateView is the parent view and user view is the subview.

Comment: - (void)rotationDetected:(UIRotationGestureRecognizer *)rotationRecognizer
{
        rotationRecognizer.rotation = M_PI_4;
        CGFloat angle = rotationRecognizer.rotation;
        duplicateView.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(duplicateView.transform, angle);
        userView.transform = duplicateView.transform;
       rotationRecognizer.rotation = 0.0;
}

Comment: And please describe the visual effect you are looking for. When a view is rotated, it's subviews are rotated along with it, so I'm not sure what you want to achieve.

Comment: The subView is a translucent view whose size is smaller then that of the parent view. When I manually rotate the parent view, the subview should also be rotated along with it.

Comment: If it's a subview of the rotated view, it will be. In your code you're adding an _additional_ transform to the subview which will rotate it further.

Answer (score 1):

If you rotate a `UIView`'s parent view the sub view will also rotate in the same way. You do not have to write any special code to make that happen.

Comment: What if I want to prevent their rotation?

Comment: You can rotate the opposite gradient value (i.e. plus or minus) to the specific subviews and they will look like they are not moving

Comment: So lets say I have build a custom floor plan map, and on the floor plan there are various map pins. If I rotate the map, will the pins remain in the correct position relative to the rotated image? I imagine I will have to apply a reverse rotation on the pins to keep them straight.